# Multiple accounts in Warframe

Tags: warframe

I started a Youtube channel and I want to play Warframe on it. Though I want to play it in two "ways": Youtube and non-Youtube. Basically I want to have 2 separate game vessels without sharing anything apart from the same account.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Like Stated in the Terms at [Warframe](https://warframe.com/en/terms) under 3. Account they dont prohibit the creation of alternate Accounts.

> The creation of alternate accounts will be handled on a case by case
>   basis, and we reserve the right to remove accounts used to circumvent
>   any form of restrictions to the game or the Service including the
>   official Warframe forums.

So as long you don't use the account to circumvent certain restrictions you should be safe.

Simply create another account using a different ID and e-mail address.

Comment: Definetly different mail adress. You can only bind one email to one account ;)

Comment: good to Know Ill edit my answer